# Command line tool to resize image files to max size and change casing

Tags: image, file, batch-file, converters, jpeg

Suppose you have a folder with a lot of images. Filesizes and extensions differ per image and you want to be consistent in the same format. Is there a way to:

- Make filename uppercase and extension lowercase (if not already): EXAMPLE.jpg
- Convert image to .jpg if current type is other than jpg. (could be png, tiff, bmp, psd etc)
- Convert image to max. 5 MB if currently larger, but only resize if it is more than 5MB else leave it as is. The image dimensions don't need to be changed.

How can this be done?

Excuse me if this is a too broad question, but I have looked for all kinds of tools like BulkRenameUtility, Flash Renamer, JPEG resizer, ReaConverter. All excellent tools, but they all use a GUI and I'd like to create one solution that runs every night on a windows server automatically. The renaming part could be done with command line for BRU or flashrenamer perhaps, but how about the conversion to JPEG with max filesize...

Comment: For the resizing PART take a look here : http://forum.obviousidea.com/threads/143-image-resizing-api-library-programming-command-line-with-Light-Image-Resizer

Comment: Ok will check it out. Maybe able to combina this with other command tool, thanks!

Comment: Irfanview has a command line mode and the switches to give you information about the files, plus the ability to resize and change compression ratio, and picture format.

Comment: Thanks @foxidrive didn't think of irfanview, but worked with it years ago, will check out its command line functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with ImageMagick, Bash and the `tr` commandline tool. Write a shell script using the following elements.

First, rename the file:

```
 file_orig=${input}                                           # ex.: "aBcD.png"
 file_upper=$(echo $(basename ${input}) | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]") # ex.: "ABCD"
```

Then, use ImageMagick's `convert` command to convert to JPEG:

```
 convert ${input} ${file_upper}.jpg                           # ex.: "ABCD.jpg"
```

This is the most basic usage. It does not yet apply your conditions about the file sizes. You could check the file size with basic shell commands and run commands conditional of the check results.

But here is a more elegant method: ImageMagick (if its version is IM v6.5.8-2 or newer) can use `-define jpeg:extent={size}` for JPEG output, where `{size}` is specified with a file size suffix (ex.: `5000kb` or `5mb` for 5 MByte).

It works like this: `convert` creates multiple versions of the JPEG output. It tries with different quality settings, until it gets as close as possible to the file size given without exceeding it. It writes the result repeatably into temporary files. Once the appropriate quality + size is found, it outputs the final image to the given output filename and deletes the temporary files:

```
 convert                   \
   -define jpeg:extent=5mb \
    ${input}               \
    ${file_upper}.jpg
```

ImageMagick is available for Windows too. (I tested on Linux and Mac OSX.)